# I have to select the checkbox two times to check/uncheck in jTable

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, jtable

I have a jTable code i intend to use, but the problem with it is that when i click on the checkbox once it doesn't select/deselect it, instead i have to click twice. But if i select any other cell in the row except the one containing the checkbox the purpose is solved.

HERE IS MY CODE :

```
public class TableSelectionTest extends JFrame implements ListSelectionListener {
private final int COLUMN_COUNT = 5;
private TblModel model;
public TableSelectionTest() {
    initialize();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pack();
}
private void initialize() {
    List data = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Object record[] = new Object[COLUMN_COUNT];
    record[0] = Boolean.FALSE;
    for (int j = 1; j < COLUMN_COUNT; j++)
    {
        record[j] = new Integer(j);
    }
    data.add(record);
}
model = new TblModel(data);
JTable table = new JTable(model);
table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener (this);
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
getContentPane().add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
TableSelectionTest f = new TableSelectionTest();
f.show();
}

class TblModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private List data;
    public TblModel(List data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return COLUMN_COUNT;
    }
    public int getRowCount() {
        return data == null ? 0 : data.size();
    }
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        getRecord(rowIndex)[columnIndex] = value;
        super.fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
    }
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return getRecord(rowIndex)[columnIndex];
    }
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        if(columnIndex == 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        if (data == null || data.size() == 0) {
            return Object.class;
        }
        Object o = getValueAt(0, columnIndex);
        return o == null ? Object.class : o.getClass();
    }
    private Object[] getRecord(int rowIndex) {
        return (Object[]) data.get(rowIndex);
    }
}

public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
    if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
        ListSelectionModel lsm = (ListSelectionModel) e.getSource();
        int index = lsm.getMinSelectionIndex();
        if(model.getRecord(index)[0] == Boolean.FALSE)
            model.setValueAt(Boolean.TRUE, index, 0);
        else if(model.getRecord(index)[0] == Boolean.TRUE)
            model.setValueAt(Boolean.FALSE, index, 0);
    }
}
}
```

Please reply soon as it is bugging me a lot
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Your ListSelectionListener is conflicting with your TableCellEditor.

Ideally, I'd suggest removing the ListSelectionListener.  It's not necessary since the TableCellEditor just calls setValueAt() in order to update the cell's contents.

Answer (score 1):

Amplifying on @rob's correct answer, your `ListSelectionListener` is resetting the value with each change; tab through the table to see the effect. Your `setValueAt()` method already updates the data; add this `println()` to see:

```
for (Object row : data) {
    System.out.println(((Object[]) row)[0]);
}
```

As an aside, consider making your `data` more generic and avoid deprecated methods such as `show()`.

Addendum: Here's an example; see also [*How to Use Tables*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class TableSelectionTest extends JFrame {

    private final int COLUMN_COUNT = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TableSelectionTest();
            }
        });
    }

    public TableSelectionTest() {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JTable table = new JTable(new TblModel());
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        this.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    class TblModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private Random rnd = new Random();
        private List<Boolean> data = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

        public TblModel() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                data.add(rnd.nextBoolean());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return COLUMN_COUNT;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object value, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            if (columnIndex == 0) {
                data.set(rowIndex, (Boolean) value);
            }
            super.fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
            for (Boolean b : data) {
                System.out.print(b + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            if (columnIndex == 0) {
                return data.get(rowIndex);
            } else {
                return columnIndex;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return columnIndex == 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            if (columnIndex == 0) {
                return Boolean.class;
            } else {
                return Integer.class;
            }
        }
    }
}
```